Error: Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found
I am having a lot of trouble connecting to the network. I am running on a raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04 Server (no gui) and I've chosen to do my configuration with nmcli. I "know" that my wifi works on the robot because I am able to connect with the "one Boston" connection to my other local network. Eduroam has a certificate and some more complications.
Do you see what may be wrong? I've tried a lot and googled a lot.
sudo nmcli conn up eduroam

Error: Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=231c86ef-c750-4707-8ac5-82111516f91c + NM_DEVICE=wlan0' to get more details.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nmcli conn
NAME        UUID                                  TYPE  DEVICE
eduroam     231c86ef-c750-4707-8ac5-82111516f91c  wifi  --
one boston  69a9adb0-8dad-44be-9e00-b06df7bc316e  wifi  --

Output from nmcli conn show
connection.id:                          eduroam
connection.uuid:                        231c86ef-c750-4707-8ac5-82111516f91c
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.interface-name:              wlan0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   0
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
802-1x.optional:                        no
802-1x.eap:                             peap
802-1x.identity:                        rpsalas@brandeis.edu
802-1x.anonymous-identity:              --
802-1x.pac-file:                        --
802-1x.ca-cert:                         --
802-1x.ca-cert-password:                <hidden>
802-1x.ca-cert-password-flags:          0 (none)
802-1x.ca-path:                         --
802-1x.subject-match:                   --
802-1x.altsubject-matches:              --
802-1x.domain-suffix-match:             --
802-1x.client-cert:                     --
802-1x.client-cert-password:            <hidden>
802-1x.client-cert-password-flags:      0 (none)
802-1x.phase1-peapver:                  --
802-1x.phase1-peaplabel:                --
802-1x.phase1-fast-provisioning:        --
802-1x.phase1-auth-flags:               0x0 (none)
802-1x.phase2-auth:                     mschapv2
802-1x.phase2-autheap:                  --
802-1x.phase2-ca-cert:                  --
802-1x.phase2-ca-cert-password:         <hidden>
802-1x.phase2-ca-cert-password-flags:   0 (none)
802-1x.phase2-ca-path:                  --
802-1x.phase2-subject-match:            --
802-1x.phase2-altsubject-matches:       --
802-1x.phase2-domain-suffix-match:      --
802-1x.phase2-client-cert:              --
802-1x.phase2-client-cert-password:     <hidden>
802-1x.phase2-client-cert-password-flags:0 (none)
802-1x.password:                        <hidden>
802-1x.password-flags:                  0 (none)
802-1x.password-raw:                    <hidden>
802-1x.password-raw-flags:              0 (none)
802-1x.private-key:                     --
802-1x.private-key-password:            <hidden>
802-1x.private-key-password-flags:      0 (none)
802-1x.phase2-private-key:              --
802-1x.phase2-private-key-password:     <hidden>
802-1x.phase2-private-key-password-flags:0 (none)
802-1x.pin:                             <hidden>
802-1x.pin-flags:                       0 (none)
802-1x.system-ca-certs:                 no
802-1x.auth-timeout:                    0
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   eduroam
802-11-wireless.mode:                   infrastructure
802-11-wireless.band:                   --
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  --
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            --
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
802-11-wireless.powersave:              0 (default)
802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan:           0x1 (default)
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --

proxy.pac-script:                       --
